# Why do the comments for tomcat Bootstrap main function indicate it is for test only

Tags: tomcat, testing, comments, program-entry-point, bootstrapping

I am studying tomcat 7 source code. I found that the comments for the main function in Bootstrap indicate it is for test only:

```
/**
 * Main method, used for testing only.
 *
 * @param args Command line arguments to be processed
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

I think it is the entry point for tomcat server. Is there any reason for this comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the Tomcat source code dates back to the origins of the project. The purpose of some classes has changed over time but the comments haven't always kept up. This looks like one of those cases. Bootstrap is indeed the entry point for a Tomcat instance started from the command line. I'll get the comments updated.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?rev=1311212&view=rev and http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?rev=1311213&view=rev